# Android ARM undefined reference to __aeabi_uidiv clang

Tags: android, android-ndk, clang

I'm trying to compile a library for Android ARM with clang (specifically ffmpeg+libvpx) and I got these nasty messages like:

```
error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_idivmod'
error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_uidiv'
```

Well I understand that these functions are not accessible for ARM in clang and there should be a replacement. 
Does Android NDK or clang somehow provides it? I mean well it's 2019 I don't think I have to implement them by myself.
How do you handle such situations?

Comment: Are you using an old version of the NDK?

Comment: Nope. Actually I know what's going on. I need to use either libgcc or compiler-rt for these functions to link.

Comment: Yes, but that's the compiler's job, not yours. Without knowing what you did to cause this I can't guess as to what went wrong though.